# asp.net login control doesnt work

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I put a login control and it wont let me inside the site. 
(I even tried to use login control to retrieve and reset password. still wont work).

Here is a section of my web.config file. Yesterday, i fixed that issue by changing the properties in the add tag..but today the problem repeats itself.

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

```
     <add name="YourGuruDB" connectionString="Data Source=DIMA-00AA1DA557;Initial Catalog=model;Integrated Security=True"/>
        <add name="modelConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=DIMA-00AA1DA557;Initial Catalog=model;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
        <add name="LocalSqlServer2" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='D:\Documents and Settings\Dima\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite10\App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>


  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>



    <membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add
          name="MyMembershipProvider"
          type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
          connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer2"
          minRequiredPasswordLength="2"
          minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
          maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="1000"
          passwordAttemptWindow="1000"
          />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <roleManager enabled="true" />

    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name="MyAppCookie"
             loginUrl="~/Registration.aspx"
             protection="All"
             timeout="30" path="/" />
    </authentication>
```

Comment: Careful with your words, when I read your title I thought of Chicken Little, just after he declared "the sky is falling" and panic ensued.... something is wrong with your configuration... what errors?  And is your connection string correct?

Comment: i dont get any error, what i get, is failure to login, each time i try to login through the login control. But i am able to retrieve a password. not to login!!... i think that one of the properties in the config file is preventing me to accept the password..

Comment: Aspnet.mdf connection string: data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true

Comment: you have an existing database, you can also insert the default ASP.NET Membership tables, stored procedures and stuff using a utility called "aspnet_regsql" which you can find in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727

Comment: i dont need nor do i know how to use aspnet_regsql

Comment: Double click on aspnet_regsql and it will start a wizard!

Comment: And by the way, the LocalServer2 connectionstring will only work when you have a local Sql Server (express) database which instance name is SQLExpress

Comment: i have SQLExpress installed, but i am not doing it that way, and i dont think it is needed. I am using Visual Studio 2010. i dont see where that aspnet_regsql is

Comment: You can find aspnet_regsql.exe in directory  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 or C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319. The wizard will ask you which database you want to use. Choose "YourGuruDb"

Comment: When you finished the wizard, it should not throw that exception anymore!

Comment: http://www.nayyeri.net/why-asp-net-2-0-login-control-doesnt-work-with-sql-membership-provider,,, i am reading this article i think the answer should be there...and why to use YourGuru. it is a seperate database..that isnt used to register and validate login controls

Answer (score 4):

Does "LocalSqlServer" exists as connection string? 
What errors are you getting?

You should find in your ConnectionString section something like:

```
 <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="<YourConnectionString>" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

And did you enabled FormsAuthentication?

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms loginUrl="<YourLoginPage>" timeout="2880"/>
   </authentication>
```

Comment: <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="MyAppCookie"
             loginUrl="~/Registration.aspx"
             protection="All"
             timeout="30" path="/" />

    </authentication>

Comment: This answer looks correct since you updated your question. The connection string name is wrong.

Comment: Whats wrong with the connection string name? and why do i see red Xes near the dabase icons when i open my server explorer?

Comment: In the `<connectionStrings>` section, you named your connection string `YourGuruDB`, but in the `<membership>` section, you told the provider to look for `LocalSqlServer`. You must make the names the same thing.

Comment: well i did change the name of the string , to the second one (the first ,YourGuruDB, is a connection string that i got)! i got this exception System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'....i think it means that the string name is incorrect. How do i get the string name of the aspnetDB.mdf ??!? do i need to set it myself in the config file?

Comment: Aspnet.mdf connection string: data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true

Comment: If you have an existing database, you can also insert the default ASP.NET Membership tables, stored procedures and stuff using a utility called "aspnet_regsql" which you can find in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727

Comment: It gives me an exception saying that localserver was already added (that is the name of the connection string that i added and exists under the provider tag <add ...connectionStringname="Localserver"). i dont think the problem is with the connection string, cause, i am able to register users, reset pass, retrieve pass , but not login, and i can see the details inside the aspnetDB

Comment: Try using a different name than LocalServer. Can you rename to LocalServer2?? It might be possible that LocalServer is already defined at a lower level. That configuration is inherited by your application.

Comment: i tried the whole thing..still wont work. added all my config file

Comment: Im missing the connectionString section!

Comment: You web.config should have something like this: <connectionStrings> <add name="LocalServer2" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/> </connectionStrings> Double check if you have the name attribute right (should be LocalSqlServer2)

Comment: <add name="LocalSqlServer2" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='D:\Documents and Settings\Dima\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite10\App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

Here it is...seems to be fine, i took it as it is from aspnetDB

Answer (score 0):

Are you resetting the password or being emailed your actual password?
Have you checked the Membership table to make sure that you have not been locked out?

I can see you have `maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="1000"` but if you have been playing about with the config the maybe you locked yourself out before changing the settings.

Comment: no, i am retrieving it with an event, i revent it from being sent to the email. I am not locking myself out, I checked in the database. Lockedout is false.